# Cypress.io doesn't take index.js despite configuration

Tags: node.js, json, cypress

As in title, I'm not able to use any command from commands.js. BeforeEach in index.js is also not running. My configuration:

cypress.json:

```
"supportFile": "./support/index.js",
```

index.js:

```
require('./commands')
import "./commands"

beforeEach(function () {
    cy.clearLocalStorage();
    cy.visit('');
})
```

tests are running without beforeach and commands. When I put beforeEach to test file it works. Can it be related to system permissions? I'm using ubuntu.

Comment: Why would system permissions be a factor? If they were you'd get errors.

Comment: I'm just wondering

Comment: Nothing wrong with wondering, but finding out is the next step. If you can't get any errors as confirmation then it's probably not permissions but something else, like the way you're using Cypress.

Comment: I don't get any errors, just cypress test runner doesn't show before each block. I checked paths 5 times. I also compared configuration to cypress documentation and looks correct

Answer (score 0):

Just ran an experiment, it worked ok with no `supportFile` entry in cypress.json (standard folder structure), but adding the entry I needed `/cypress` in the path (on Win10)

```
"supportFile": "./cypress/support/index.js"
```

Comment: The same, nothing change. I'm using ubuntu 18.

Comment: Bad luck. You should try some variations. Also, use a command in the beforeEach that is easier to confirm, like `cy.log()`.